# Unique search results in Rails 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would appreciate your help regarding this issue I am having.

I have the following in my controller method.

```
@search=Book.book2_scope.search(params[:search])
```

The problem is that the @search contain duplicate entries.

I would like to have only distinct entries (distinct id).

I tried the following solution:

```
@search = Book.search(params[:search])

@search.book2_scope.select("DISTINCT(id), books.*")
```

But it seems to be a solution for rails 3, not rails 2.3.5.

Any suggestion is most welcome.

Thank You

Comment: what is `search` method?

Answer (score 0):

The duplicates are probably a consequence of your `book2_scope` scope. You may be able to rewrite that to ensure only distinct records are returned.